# Como restringir archivos php

Tags: php, apache, xampp

Queria su apoyo con lo siguiente, tengo instalado en XAAMP como servidor para mis proyectos php, lo que necesito es que esos proyectos alojados en htdocs dentro de XAAmp no se permitan visualizar a otros usuarios de ese servidor, me explico mejor , ese servidor lo comparto con otros usuarios que tambien alojan sus proyectos, lo que yo deseo es que no pueden entrar a ver la codificación de mis carpetas como puedo hacer muchas gracias

Comment: Esto realmente no es una pregunta de apache/xampp sino de servidores. Edítala para añadir más datos: ¿qué servidor estás usando (Windows/Linux...)? ¿Los usuarios se conectan con diferentes cuentas al servidor? ¿Cómo se conectan al servidor (ftp/vpn...)?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que tenemos un "servidor" que tiene windows 7 , es una estacion de trabajo a la que le pusimos el xaamp para alojar unas carpetas con archivos php para unas webs que tenemos , lo que pasa es que asi como yo pongo mi carpeta con mi proyecto hay otros compañeros que ponen sus proyectos, cualquiera puede entrar a la carpeta , todos entramos con la misma cuenta con escritorio remoto, escuche que se podria usar htaccess pero no se muy bien como , muchas gracias por contestar a mi pregunta

Comment: ¿Quieres evitar que entren a tu carpeta una vez se han logueado de manera remota en el servidor? Si es eso, no se puede (al menos, no sin un programa). Con .htaccess puedes evitar que desde el servidor web se accedan a los ficheros de otra carpeta, pero desde el servidor web, si tienen acceso remoto a la estación de trabajo, pueden hacer lo que quieran (incluido modificar .htaccess para darse permisos para ver tus ficheros). Si por otra parte, en lugar de dar acceso directo a la estación de trabajo, lo que hicieses fuese poner un servidor ftp, entonces sí podrías limitar quién accede a qué.

Comment: Muchas gracias eso se tendra que hacer, ya tengo mas claro el panorama de que debo hacer, saludos